# Change event being fired on select tag when option isn't clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a change event bound to a select tag. The first option in the select tag is disabled because I am using it as the default text for the menu. If the user clicks on the select tag, hovers over an option without selecting it, and then clicks outside of the select menu twice the change event is being fired. How can I prevent this change event from being fired.

The HTML

```
<select id="select">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Title</option>
    <optgroup label="things">
        <option>cars</option>
        <option>boats</option>
        <option>world</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

The jQuery

```
$('#hide').click(function(){
    $('#select').hide();
});
$('#show').click(function(){
    $('#select').show();
});
$('#select').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

The code is just a sample of what my problem is. I added the buttons because in my real code I am hiding the select menu when the user clicks outside of it.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPpD6/1/) with the above code.

**EDIT**

After looking at comments it looks to be a firefox specific issue as it works fine in Internet Explorer, Chorme, and Safari.

Comment: I don't get the behavior you claim you get. When I click twice it doesn't do anything as expected.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you're describing.

Comment: Try hovering over boats and then clicking the hide button twice.

Comment: Do you want to prevent false "changes" or do you only care about false changes in the case where the default value is the current value but remains the same on change event?

Comment: I want to prevent false "changes"

Comment: I am testing in firefox 17.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always associate some data on the select with the current value and validate that it actually changed.

```
$('#hide').click(function(){
    $('#select').hide();
});
$('#show').click(function(){
    $('#select').show();
});
$('#select').data('currVal', 'Title');
$('#select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != $(this).data('currVal') {
        // this is actual value change
        alert($(this).val());
        $(this).data('currVal', $(this).val());
    }
});
```

I have updated the original fiddle with solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/TPpD6/4/

Comment: Updated the link in my answer

Comment: Thanks for all your help Mike, I am going to change my code to listen for click events on the options instead of the change event to avoid this problem. Your code did help me realize a solution for another problem I am facing though.